# Binding TextBox Text value to ComboBox.SelectedItem, and list from selected item of a ComboBox to another ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox, textbox

So I have a class "Worker" and a BindingList which is bound to a ComboBox.

```
    workers = new BindingList<Worker>();
    //// .. An "Add" button is somewhere there to add "Worker" objects to the list
    //ComboBox Workers List
    cbWorkersList.DataSource = workers;
    cbWorkersList.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

I want to bind the "Text" field in a TextBox to the "Name" property of the selected "Worker" object, in the ComboBox.

Now I've done it by using the "cbWorkersList_SelectedIndexChanged" event handler, manually modifying  txtWorkerName.Text property:

```
private void cbWorkersList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbWorkersList.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        txtWorkerName.Text = workers[workers.IndexOf((Worker)cbWorkersList.SelectedItem)].Name;
    }
}
```

I tried to bound the TextBox in this way:

```
InitializeComponent();
txtWorkerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", cbWorkersList, "Text");
```

But it is only updating the TextBox if I click on other item on the list, if I use arrow keys to change the selection, the TextBox text field is not changing.

Is there a way to truly bind them so that if a ComboBox item is selected, the text field will change accordingly?

While on this topic, I also have other 2 ComboBoxes, and I would like to bind 1 to a list which is inside the others' ComboBox object.
What I want is a solution with the following logic:

```
cbPositions.Items = ((<Shift>)cbShifts.SelcetedItem).PositionsList
```

when 
cbPositions is a ComboBox which should be populated with "Position" objects.
And cbShifts is a ComboBox which is populated with "Shift" objects, where each "Shift" contains a list of Positions.

How can I bind them so every time I choose an other Shift from the list, the Positions ComboBox will be populated with the Position objects from the Shift.PositionList?

And also, I would like to know if it's possible to bind the "Items" of a ComboBox to a List (my workers list in this example), not with code, but in the designer(Application Settings or DataBindings)?

Comment: It's unclear how you setup data-bidding and without having your code, we may have completely different thing in mind rather than what you have. Consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: `While on this topic...`  One question at a time please.  Show us how your ComboBox is being data supplied.  Generally, it would be a DataBound to a source, like a DataTable, and not another control.

Comment: Add the ValueMember property: `cbWorkersList.ValueMember = ...;`  Set the property to the "id" property of the list.  Then your TextBox databinding should look something like this: `txtWorkerName.DataBindings.Add("Text", workers, "Name");`

Comment: Awesome that works ! only that when I change the text, the Name of the worker changes, but the Text displayed in the ComboBox doesn't.

Comment: `but the Text displayed in the ComboBox doesn't.`  That would require a PropertyChanged interface notification on that property.

Comment: Awesome that helped alot! Thank you very much. Can you help me figure out the other questions too?